# Is it possible to use 璟 for a boy's given name?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to choose a name for my boy and am wondering if i can use 璟 as his given name?

I have googled this but it seems not a lot of people have this name. Instead, most of them use this word 景

Answer (score 2, accepted):

璟:ｊǐｎｇ【形】玉的光彩 (The brilliance of jade)

玉 is a neutral name, suitable for male or female. I don't see any reason 璟 would not be.

From [起名网](http://www.qimingw.net/html/nanhaiqimingchangyongzi/506.html)

> 二、带璟字的男孩名字

> (璟超)(璟竑)(璟麟)(璟然)(璟贤)(璟钰)

> (璟朝)(璟鸿)(璟凌)(璟荣)(璟显)(璟煜)

> *........ 中略 ........*

> (彬璟)(贯璟)(君璟)(群璟)(夏璟)(余璟)

Comment: Thanks @Tang, your link is helpful a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Of course. It means the brilliance of of jade. In Chinese name,  璟 means a man who are gentlemanlike and warm. It's quite stable to be used in name.

Comment: Thanks @Sharon for your explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sure.

Seems this word is only used for name nowadays.